# VBA/MySQL issue using ODBC connector

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, odbc, dsn

I have been struggling with this for a few days now. Any help much appreciated.

Trying to connect to MySQL database using Excel VBA, on a PC with the following:

Excel 2007
Windows 7 x64 Home Premium
MySQL 5.5
MySQL ODBC Connector 5.1, 64 bit

In the Excel VBA I have referenced Microsoft ActiveX Objects 2.8 Library.

The VBA I am using to connect is:

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Public Sub ConnectDB()
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & "SERVER=localhost;" & "DATABASE=test;" & "USER=root;" & "PASSWORD=PWhere;" & "Option=3"
End Sub
```

Every time I run this I get the error dialog: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

MySQL service is definitely running.

I have used Windows Data Source Administrator to check that MySQL ODBC Connector 5.1 is present and correct: it is, checks out OK when I try to create a DSN in this way.

Looking through the VBA project reference options, I note the options to reference a whole host of different ADO Libraries, including (Multi-dimensional) options and library versions 2.0,2.1,2.5,2.6,2.7, and 6.0 - maybe the answer lies in one of these?

Any more details required, let me know.

Comment: Never worked with 64 bit so I am not sure if this link will help you but have a look and see if it helps? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=619916

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use either the 32 or 64 bits version depending on the version of **Excel**, not Windows. So even if you run Windows 7 64 bits, I believe Excel 2007 only comes in 32 bits so you would need to use the 32 bits mysql connector.

See also this [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55523) that is similar to your issue.

Comment: Thanks worked for me. Also since MySQL ODBC 5.2 the connection string is a little different: [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/)

Answer (score 4):

I got similar message when moved my application to other system with different version of driver - it looks like misspelled driver name causes identical message. To find correct driver name and make application driver version independent I use the following code:

```
    Public Function Get_Driver() As String

    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    Dim l_Registry As Object
    Dim l_RegStr As Variant
    Dim l_RegArr As Variant
    Dim l_RegValue As Variant

    Get_Driver = ""
    Set l_Registry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    l_Registry.enumvalues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers", l_RegStr, l_RegArr

    For Each l_RegValue In l_RegStr
        If InStr(1, l_RegValue, "MySQL ODBC", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Get_Driver = l_RegValue
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set l_Registry = Nothing
End Function
```